# Alarm delay in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

I have an application which set an alarm on receiving a FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) push notification. Its working fine normally.

But, when I reboot/restart the device, alarm took time for ringing. I tried by adding **ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED** broadcast receiver to reset alarm. 
But, when the BOOT_COMPLETED event is fired after receiving push notification.

So, there is a delay in ringing alarm.

This is my code to set alarm

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), ALARM_ID, alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, pendingIntent);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, pendingIntent);
} else {
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000, pendingIntent);
}
```

So, How can I identify whether the device is rebooting or not while receiving push notification?

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: edited my question with code

Comment: I suggest you read this, and use the `JobScheduler` for API 21+: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling. At list until the `Work Manager` (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is bug free..